# Search for file in directory with multiple directories

Tags: java

Here's my goal. I want to be able to pass a parent directory and a filename to a method that searches for that specific file in the directory and any sub-directories. Below is the code I have been working with but can not get it to do exactly what I want. It will find the file I specify but will not return anything.

```
private static File findFile(File dir, String name) {
    String file     = "";
    File[] dirlist  = dir.listFiles();

    search:
        for(int i = 0; i < dirlist.length; i++) {
            if(dirlist[i].isDirectory()) {
                findFile(dirlist[i], name);
            } else if(dirlist[i].getName().matches(name)) {
                file = dirlist[i].toString();
                break search;
            }
        }

    return new File(file);
}
```

I know that when the method finds a directory and calls itself it resets the file variable which is where I am storing the found file. So that is why I am getting a blank return. I am not sure how to accomplish this goal or if it's even possible.

Comment: Aside: you could / should use a regular "break" rather than "break label" here.  (A plain return is better still as @chssPly76 points out.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're not returning anything from the recursive call:

```
if(dirlist[i].isDirectory()) {
    findFile(dirlist[i], name); // <-- here
} else if(dirlist[i].getName().matches(name)) {
```

I would do the following:

```
private static File findFile(File dir, String name) {
  File result = null; // no need to store result as String, you're returning File anyway
  File[] dirlist  = dir.listFiles();

  for(int i = 0; i < dirlist.length; i++) { 
    if(dirlist[i].isDirectory()) {
      result = findFile(dirlist[i], name);
      if (result!=null) break; // recursive call found the file; terminate the loop
    } else if(dirlist[i].getName().matches(name)) {
      return dirlist[i]; // found the file; return it
    }
  }
  return result; // will return null if we didn't find anything
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the file doesn't exist in directory and it will raise exception

Answer (score 1):

In fact there are many solutions to do the job.
I assume that you want to find ***a unique file*** (or the first one) found in a directory tree that matches with the fileName.
It is a problem of optimization because there are multiple ways to explore solutions, and we want to find an acceptable solution.

**1- Solution using FileUtils.listFiles**

```
public static File searchFileWithFileUtils(final File file, final String fileName) {
    File target = null;
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(file, null, true);
        for (File currFile : files) {
            if (currFile.isFile() && currFile.getName().equals(fileName)) {
                target = currFile;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

The solution using the library `FileUtils` is not a suitable solution because the method `FileUtils#listFiles()` loads all the directory/folder tree (the cost is expensive !).
We don't need to know all the tree, we can choose a better algorithm which stops when the file is found.

**2- Recursive Solution**

```
public static File searchFileRecursive(final File file, final String search) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            File target = searchFileRecursive(f, search);
            if(target != null) {
                return target;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (search.equals(file.getName())) {
            return file;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The algorithm tests if the file exists inside any folder. If not, it tries subfolder of the current folder... recursively. If the file is not found in the current branch it tries another subfolder.

The exploration is deep, and for any file in a deepness of 1 the algorithm will explore the entirety of previous subfolders (previous branches are completely explored !).
This algorithm has the best performances for files in a deep location inside the first branch.

In the majority of cases, the file location is not deep, so let explore another algorithm that works in most of cases.

**3- Fastest Solution : exploration by deepness**

```
public static File searchFileByDeepness(final String directoryName, final String fileName) {
    File target = null;
    if(directoryName != null && fileName != null) {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        if(directory.isDirectory()) {
            File file = new File(directoryName, fileName);
            if(file.isFile()) {
                target = file;
            }
            else {
                List<File> subDirectories = getSubDirectories(directory);
                do {
                    List<File> subSubDirectories = new ArrayList<File>();
                    for(File subDirectory : subDirectories) {
                        File fileInSubDirectory = new File(subDirectory, fileName);
                        if(fileInSubDirectory.isFile()) {
                            return fileInSubDirectory;
                        }
                        subSubDirectories.addAll(getSubDirectories(subDirectory));
                    }
                    subDirectories = subSubDirectories;
                } while(subDirectories != null && ! subDirectories.isEmpty());
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

private static List<File> getSubDirectories(final File directory) {
    File[] subDirectories = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(final File current, final String name) {
            return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
        }
    });
    return Arrays.asList(subDirectories);
}
```

For each deepness, the algorithm searches the file inside all folders of the same level. If the file is not found, it tries the next level (deepness++).
Due to the parallel exploration (symmetry), this solution is suitable in most of cases.

**Comparison:**

```
public class FileLocationFinder {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String rootFolder = args[0];
        String fileName = args[1];

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        File target = searchFileWithFileUtils(new File(rootFolder), fileName);
        System.out.println(target.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        target = searchFileRecursive(new File(rootFolder), fileName);
        System.out.println(target.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        target = searchFileByDeepness(rootFolder, fileName);
        System.out.println(target.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("Duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
    }


    // Solution with FileUtils#listFiles
    //--------------------------------------------

    public static File searchFileWithFileUtils(final File file, final String fileName) {
        File target = null;
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(file, null, true);
            for (File currFile : files) {
                if (currFile.isFile() && currFile.getName().equals(fileName)) {
                    target = currFile;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return target;
    }


    // Recursive solution
    //--------------------------------------------

    public static File searchFileRecursive(final File file, final String search) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            for (File f : files) {
                File target = searchFileRecursive(f, search);
                if(target != null) {
                    return target;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (search.equals(file.getName())) {
                return file;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    // Fastest solution
    //--------------------------------------------

    public static File searchFileByDeepness(final String directoryName, final String fileName) {
        File target = null;
        if(directoryName != null && fileName != null) {
            File directory = new File(directoryName);
            if(directory.isDirectory()) {
                File file = new File(directoryName, fileName);
                if(file.isFile()) {
                    target = file;
                }
                else {
                    List<File> subDirectories = getSubDirectories(directory);
                    do {
                        List<File> subSubDirectories = new ArrayList<File>();
                        for(File subDirectory : subDirectories) {
                            File fileInSubDirectory = new File(subDirectory, fileName);
                            if(fileInSubDirectory.isFile()) {
                                return fileInSubDirectory;
                            }
                            subSubDirectories.addAll(getSubDirectories(subDirectory));
                        }
                        subDirectories = subSubDirectories;
                    } while(subDirectories != null && ! subDirectories.isEmpty());
                }
            }
        }
        return target;
    }

    private static List<File> getSubDirectories(final File directory) {
        File[] subDirectories = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(final File current, final String name) {
                return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
            }
        });
        return Arrays.asList(subDirectories);
    }
}
```

Result:

> searchFileWithFileUtils: 20186ms | searchFileRecursive: 1134ms | searchFileByDeepness: 16ms

---

**[EDIT]**
You can also use Java 8 Files API to do this job :

```
public static File searchFileJava8(final String rootFolder, final String fileName) {
    File target = null;
    Path root = Paths.get(rootFolder);
    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(root, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path, attr) ->
            path.getFileName().toString().equals(fileName))) {
        Optional<Path> path = stream.findFirst();
        if(path.isPresent()) {
            target = path.get().toFile();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return target;
}
```

But the execution time is not better (994ms).