# How to get file name from folder or under subdirectories using java

Tags: java, file, filesystems

I have to find the file names in tree view which has placed under folder or sub directories.

For example,assume directories called A,B,C...

A--B/testb.txt--C/testc.txt/......E---G/testg.txt

How to get all the file names from above directories using Java?

Comment: Please use the search function I know for a fact I have answered this question twice on SO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for file in directory with multiple directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375729/search-for-file-in-directory-with-multiple-directories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a file object for the topmost directory
- Get a list of all the `File` objects contained in that directory
- Iterate over each file:

  - If the `File` object is of type file, then print out its name
  - If the `File` object is of type directory, then repeat the above steps

Refer the `File` javadocs for more details, [reference snippet](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68) elsewhere, post your attempt and we'll help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to JAVA.Can u send the example link/source code?

Comment: @Dinesh: I've updated the post with a link to sample snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You might look to load the sub-directories lazily, as done in [FileBro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui).

[image]

Create the `JTree` pointing to the root directory of interest, & let the user take it from there.